# cython vs python different results within scipy.optimize.fsolve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I cythonized a function that I call a bunch of times in my code. The cython version and the original python code give me the same answers (within `1e-7` which I understand has something to do with cython vs. python types...not the question here but might be important).

I attempt to find the root of the function using `scipy.optimize.fsolve()`. The python version works fine, but the cython version diverges.

The code is pretty involved and has a big external file to prepare some of the arguments, so I can't post everything. I post the cython code. Full code is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyihp6wdikfbfdp/model_code_for_stack_exchange.zip).

```
def euler_outside(float b_prime, int index_b,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] b_grid, int index_y,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] y_grid,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] y_vec,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] pol_mat_b, float q,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] pol_mat_q,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] P, float beta,
                  int n_ygrid, int check=0):
    '''
    b_prime - the variable of interest. want to find b_prime that solves this
    function
    '''
    cdef double b, y, c, uc, e_ucp, eul_val
    cdef int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] uct, c_prime = np.zeros((n_ygrid,))

    b = b_grid[index_b]
    y = y_grid[index_y]

    # Get value of consumption today
    c = b + y - b_prime/q

    # Get possible values of consumption tomorrow
    if check:
        c_prime = b_prime + y_vec - b_grid[0]/q
    else:
        for i in range(n_ygrid):
            c_prime[i] = (b_prime + y_vec[i] -
                         (np.interp(b_prime, b_grid, pol_mat_b[:,i]) /
                          np.interp(b_prime, b_grid, pol_mat_q[:,i])))

    if c<0:
        return 1e10

    uc = utility_prime(c)
    uct = utility_prime(c_prime)

    e_ucp = np.inner( uct, P[index_y,:] )
    eul_val = uc - beta*q * e_ucp

    return eul_val
```

The python code is the same but w/out the `cdef` statements and type info on the arguments. I've checked to make sure the output is the same for the same input values, and it is. My question is why scipy's `fsolve` goes off the deep-end for one and not the other. I assume it's a problem with my cython?

Running python 2.7 from Anaconda. Compiling the extension module via `pyximport`.

Comment: You're declaring some of your input variables to be `float`. Are they really floats, or are they actually double? Downcasting doubles to floats might conceivably account for the difference between your Python and Cython results. If your system is ill-conditioned, the extra round-off error in the gradient might cause failure to converge.

Comment: Thanks @ali_m. Changing the floats to doubles changed the function so that  gives the exact same answer as the original python, and `fsolve()` converges to the same answer. Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the reason for the discrepancy between the results from the Python and Cython versions is that in the Cython function, several of the inputs are declared as `float`, whereas the actual Python variables are `double` precision.

The resulting increase in round-off error for the Cython function seems to be the reason why `fsolve` fails to converge - when these inputs are declared as `double` instead, the Python and Cython versions yield the exact same result, and `fsolve` converges correctly for both.

---

As an aside, cases where round-off error in the objective function prevents convergence are indicative of [ill-conditioned problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). You might want to think about whether it's possible to re-formulate your model in order to improve its numerical stability.